# How can I resize on time-series data on python

Tags: python, deep-learning, resize, scikit-image

I'm trying to do deep-learning on time-series data.

There are 12 features for each data, but every series data don't have the same amount of data.

Some shape is [48,12], and some is [54,12], I'm trying to resize them into [50,12].

All I know until now is using resize in `skimage.transform`, but I don't know if it works well or not.

Is there any other solution for doing this?

For example, one of the features in the data looks like below.
The shape is [55, 1] I would like to reshape it to [50, 1].

```
a = np.array[-5.529309, -4.6293,   -3.068647, -4.897388, -4.39951,  -4.753769, -3.729291,
 -4.973984, -5.060155, -4.686748, -4.696322, -3.939932, -3.470778, -6.209103,
 -5.586756, -4.466532, -3.193116, -5.337818, -5.596331, -4.006954, -3.499502,
 -3.413331, -6.304848, -4.322914, -4.246317, -5.759098, -5.893142, -6.381444,
 -4.52398,  -4.198445, -5.634629, -6.276124, -5.17505,  -4.322914, -4.198445,
 -4.600576, -4.39951,  -4.945261, -5.759098, -4.677173, -3.623971, -5.692076,
 -6.563361, -5.462287, -4.868664, -5.941015, -6.400594, -5.692076, -4.591002,
 -6.027186, -5.960164, -6.256975, -5.414414, -5.730374, -6.726129]
```

If I using resize, the data will look like below.

Before resize and after resize:

[image: 1]

Comment: You need to know what the time axis on your data is. If every series is 12h long but you have different number of timepoints, then skimage.transform.resize will work fine. But if every time series is data sampled every hour for some different number of hours, then you need to truncate to the shortest series, or extrapolate the shorter series.

Answer (score 0):

One choice will be using TimeSeriesResampler in tslearn.  This resizes a given time series to a fixed size you specified, by resampling data by (linear) interpolation.
https://tslearn.readthedocs.io/en/stable/gen_modules/preprocessing/tslearn.preprocessing.TimeSeriesResampler.html

Example:

```
from tslearn.preprocessing import TimeSeriesResampler
ts = np.arange(5)
new_ts = TimeSeriesResampler(sz=9).fit_transform(ts)
final_ts = np.squeeze(new_ts)
print(ts)   # [0 1 2 3 4]
print(new_ts)  # [[[0. ] [0.5] [1. ] [1.5] [2. ] [2.5] [3. ] [3.5] [4. ]]]
print(final_ts)  # [0. 0.5 1. 1.5 2. 2.5 3. 3.5 4.]
```